# ffmpeg concatenation of live streams with different codecs

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

Great information is given on https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate of how to concat two files of different codecs and I tried option "Concat filter" for two files and it works as expected.

I wish to have the concatenation of live streams from two webcams on timely basis. E.g. first camera live stream will be shown for 60 sec and then second camera live stream for 60 sec and then again first camera live stream for 60 sec.... Process continues

This is to create concatenation on fly to reduce gaps between two streams switching.

Is this possible by using ffmpeg concatenation?

Any direction will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: *ffmpeg* can read from live stream, but I don't think it can read two streams interchangeably.

Comment: hmm but strange to me why it is not capable to do so. 
Although I don't know much internally about ffmpeg but logically, what I understood of underlying structure for concatenating two files is that there will be some end of file mechanism where the
ffmpeg knows that ok, now I have to take a stream from the second file 

This approach can also be simulated to concat(or better switch) live streams based on time interval. So in place of end of file, the time interval will serve as a guide to switch to another stream.

Comment: If you mean developing a tool using ffmpeg library, I think you can. But if you mean using the command line tool, I don't think so.

Comment: Agree, I can develop a tool but what will be the approach for that? I can see something is available in gstreamer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753998/how-can-i-use-gstreamer-smpte-to-concatenate-2-video-files-with-gst-launch